# How can I find which tests are running slowly in nosetests?

Tags: python, nosetests

We've got a test suite of about 2000 tests distributed over 50-60 files, that we run with nosetests. What is the best way to figure out which tests are running slowly? I could add a start/stop timer to the setUp method of every test, but this would be cumbersome to add to every file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [nosetests `prof` documentation](https://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/plugins/prof.html) provides details on how to profile your application.  Easiest way is:

```
nosetests --with-profile
```